# How to write rspec for link shortener?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, rspec-rails

This is a method in my model

```
def event_share_url(destination: nil)
    link_options = {
      url: self.learnmore_url.present? ? learnmore_url : event_url(self.id),
      destination: destination || "other",
      asset: self,
      user: Current.user
    }

    link = Link.fetch_or_create_link link_options
    share_url = link.share_link
  end
```

How to write rspec for this model method ?

```
def share_link
    my_link = self._share_link
    link_shortener_client = LinkShortener.new({ source_url: my_link })
    
  end
```

Here is the method in link.rb with link shortener

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to test `LinkShortener` separately and then test that your method call the service.

```rb
# Assuming you've tested separately LinkShortener

describe '#share_link' do
  subject { model.share_link }
  let(:model} { create(:your_factory) }
  let(:foo) { :bar }

  it 'calls correct service' do
     expect(LinkShortener).to receive(:new).with({source_url: model._share_link})
                                           .and_return(foo)
     expect(subject).to eq(:bar)
  end
end
```

Comment: How to test link shortener seperately here ? @brcebn. I am new to rspec

Comment: In a dedicated file test. Completely separated from the other. 
I don't have the code of this service so I cannot give you any hint on it but you got the main idea.